# .Net User Control Not Firing Events

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010, user-controls

I am attempting to write a User Control.  The control will be used in a SharePoint WebPart.  For the most part, the control works, the problem is that the control does not recognize that the button was clicked.  The button event does not fire.  The code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace CU_Controls
{
    public class CheckBoxListDropDown : CheckBoxList
    {
        //First row
        public string Title { get; set; }

        private const string defaultCssResource = "CU_Controls.EmbeddedResources.DefaultStyles.css";

        //Expand or hide on start
        public bool OpenOnStart { get; set; }

        protected Panel cbddPanel;
        protected Panel headerPanel;
        protected Literal headerText;
        protected Image headerImage;

        protected Panel listPanel;

        protected Panel footerPanel;
        protected Button okayButton;
        protected Button cancelButton;

        public event EventHandler ButtonClickDemo;

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();

            this.CssClass = "cbddList";

            cbddPanel = new Panel();
            cbddPanel.CssClass = "cbddPanel";
            cbddPanel.ID = this.ClientID + "_cbddPanel";
            cbddPanel.EnableViewState = true;

            headerPanel = new Panel();
            headerPanel.ID = this.ClientID + "_headerPanel";
            headerPanel.CssClass = "cbddHeaderPanel";
            headerPanel.EnableViewState = true;

            headerText = new Literal();
            headerText.EnableViewState = true;

            headerPanel.Controls.Add(headerText);

            headerImage = new Image();
            headerImage.ID = base.ClientID + "_arrowDown";
            headerImage.CssClass = "cbddArrowDown";
            headerImage.ImageUrl = this.Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "CU_Controls.EmbeddedResources.button.gif");
            headerImage.EnableViewState = true;

            headerPanel.Controls.Add(headerImage);
            cbddPanel.Controls.Add(headerPanel);

            listPanel = new Panel();
            listPanel.ID = base.ClientID + "_listPanel";
            listPanel.CssClass = "cbddListPanel";
            listPanel.EnableViewState = true;

            cbddPanel.Controls.Add(listPanel);

            footerPanel = new Panel();
            footerPanel.ID = base.ClientID + "_footerPanel";
            footerPanel.CssClass = "cbddFooterPanel";
            footerPanel.EnableViewState = true;

            okayButton = new Button();
            okayButton.ID = this.ClientID + "_cbddOkayButton";
            okayButton.CssClass = "cbddOkayButton";
            okayButton.Text = "Ok";
            okayButton.Click += new EventHandler(okayButton_Click);
            okayButton.EnableViewState = true;

            footerPanel.Controls.Add(okayButton);
        }

        void okayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ButtonClickDemo(sender, e);
        }

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            cbddPanel.RenderBeginTag(writer);

            headerText.Text = this.Title;
            headerPanel.RenderControl(writer);

            listPanel.RenderBeginTag(writer);

            base.Render(writer);

            footerPanel.RenderControl(writer);

            listPanel.RenderEndTag(writer);
            cbddPanel.RenderEndTag(writer);

            string jqueryToggleFunction = @" 
                <script type=""text/javascript"">
                    $(document).ready(function () {{
                        $('.{0} td:even').css('background-color', '#efefef');

                        $('#{1}').live('click', function(){{ $('#{2}').toggle('fast'); }});   

                        $('#{3}').live('click', function(){{ $('#{2}').toggle('fast'); __doPostBack('{3}',''); return false; }});                                           
                    }}); 
                </script>";
            writer.Write(string.Format(jqueryToggleFunction, base.CssClass, headerImage.ClientID, listPanel.ClientID, okayButton.ClientID));

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you don't recreate all of your controls when the postback is fired.
Just add:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{                  
    base.CreateChildControls();
    if(this.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        //Your code which adds panels etc.
    }
}
```